Change the interval of socket.io
I'm making a web dashboard whit socket for real time update chart.
I've set the socket interval at 3secs for the first 12 data, this data is stored in chartDataArray. But after when there are enough data to fill my chart i would like to set the interval to 3 min. I don't know how. The logic of interval live in the angular project, in the data-service.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
